# Is it really true that $U^{-1} = U^T$ when $U$ is an orthogonal square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I read my textbook and it says $ U^{-1} = U^{T}$  when U is an orthogonal square matrix. 
I pick this matrix

$$B= \pmatrix {-1 &5&3 \\ 4&2&-4 \\-3&1&-7 }$$

but it doesn't seems the theorem holds.

Comment: What is your definition of *orthogonal*?

Comment: This is not an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: @woogie I don't agree, computing the determinant is by far not the thing to do : it will take you time and even if you find $-1$ or $1$, it will prove nothing. You have to test whether the columns constitute an orthonormal basis, which is not the case : the norm of the first column is not equal to 1... immediate.

Comment: @ JeanMarie @ Crostul

Comment: @ JeanMarie @ Crostul The question goes like this. Let U be an nun orthogonal matrix. Show that the rows of U form an orthonormal basis of $R^{n}$. I understand that if the columns of a matrix is orthonormal, then it is orthogonal. In this case, the matrix is symmetric so $A^{T}=A^{-1}$ so $ A$ so $A^{T}A=I$ now if I see  A as transpose of $A^{T}$, then  $A^{T}A=I$ has orthonormal columns, therefore, the row space of A is orthonormal. However, I was just wondering if $A^{T}=A^{-1}$ only is true to some orthogonal matrices, not all.

Comment: @Tmm An orthogonal matrix is a matrix with orthonormal columns, which means the columns are orthogonal to each other and each have *unit-length* (length of 1).  The columns of your matrix do not have length 1.  By the way, "symmetric" means $A^T=A$ not $A^T=A^{-1}$.  It is a common confusion to think an orthogonal matrix means "orthogonal columns," forgetting the length-1 part.  If $A$ merely has orthogonal columns, then $A^TA$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are the square-lengths of each of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Let me suppose your definition of an orthogonal matrix $A$ is that $A^TA=I$ must hold. It is generally true for square matrices $AB$ (over a field, or even over commutative ring) that $BA=I$ implies $AB=I$. So we have $AA^T=I$ as well, and $A^T$ satisfies the definition $A^{-1}$. (And inverses are unique if they exist.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your given matrix is not orthogonal. An orthogonal matrix has orthogonal column vectors, meaning that their inner product should be zero. This is not the case for your matrix. If you take the inner product of the first row and third column from your matrix you get 2, not 0.